# Implementing [Authorize(Roles = "something")] with JWT in asp.net

Tags: c#, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization, jwt

I'm new to JWT and authorization in general. In our.NET 4.7.2 web application, we have an ApplicationPrincipal.cs that has a constructor that takes two arguments: IPrincipal object and UserAccount object. We'd use this in our JWT token validation's SetPrincipalAsync method. Up until now, we've always being passing a useId in JWT payload in order to create a UserAccount object off of it. But, now we have an api controller that we're making use of Authorize attribute with a Role (let say "randomName" that's encoded in JWT payload) and we're not asking for a userId in JWT payload. I can have a second constructor in my ApplicationPrincipal class to only accept a IPrincipal object in the case where I'm authorizing a request without userId, but then the Identity would be null.

I'm able to successfully validate the JWT token and return a claimsPrincipal object; But, when I test my api using Postman it returns 401 - Not Authorized.

```cs
public class ApplicationIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public ApplicationIdentity(UserAccount account)
    {
        Name = account.FullName;
        Account = account;
    }

    public UserAccount Account { get; }
    public string AuthenticationType => "JWT";
    public bool IsAuthenticated => true;
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class ApplicationPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private readonly IPrincipal _principal;
    public IIdentity Identity { get; }

    public ApplicationPrincipal(IPrincipal principal, UserAccount account)
    {
        _principal = principal;
        Identity = new ApplicationIdentity(account);
    }

    public ApplicationPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        _principal = principal;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role) => _principal.IsInRole(role);
}

public class TokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken
        )
    {
        try
        {
            var (principal, jwtSecurityToken) = await ValidateJwtAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(true);
            var payload = ValidatePayload(jwtSecurityToken);

            await SetPrincipalAsync(principal, payload).ConfigureAwait(true);

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
        {
            return request.CreateApiErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return request.CreateApiErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }

    private static async Task SetPrincipalAsync(IPrincipal principal, JWTPayload payload)
    {
        if (!Guid.TryParse(payload.UserId, out var userId) && payload.api?.version != "someName")
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Token does not have valid user ID.");
        }

        if (payload.api?.version == "someName")
        {
            var myPrincipal = new ApplicationPrincipal(principal);
            HttpContext.Current.User = myPrincipal;
        }
        else
        {
            var myPrincipal = new ApplicationPrincipal(principal);
            var handler = new Account(userId, comeOtherValue);

            var account = await CacheManager.Instance.GetOrAddAsync(handler).ConfigureAwait(true);

            if (account == null)
            {
                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Could not find user account.");
            }

            myPrincipal = new ApplicationPrincipal(principal, account);
            HttpContext.Current.User = myPrincipal;
        }
    }

  private static async Task<(IPrincipal Principal, JwtSecurityToken Token)> ValidateJwtAsync(string token, string requestingApi)
        {
            // the rest of the code

            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
            SecurityToken securityToken;
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            try
            {
                claimsPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(
                    token,
                    validationParameters,
                    out securityToken
                );

                if (requestingApi.Contains("the specific api with Role"))
                {
                    var ci = new ClaimsIdentity();
                    ci.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "roleName")); //role name applied on the api
                    claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(ci);
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                // some code
            }

            var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)securityToken;
            if (jwtToken == null)
            {
                //some code
            }

            return (claimsPrincipal, jwtToken);
        }
}
```

My goal is to apply `[Authorize(Roles = "randomName")]` to the controller based on the JWT payload which has a specific nested property:
`{"http://clients":  {"api" : {"version1" : "randomName"}}`

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Well your authorization rule is based `ClaimsPrincipal` having particular roles, however, nowhere in your code I can see those roles being added to the principal.

Comment: I do not see the implementation of _principal.IsInRole(role);.... Can you show that? Also when you say "apply [Authorize(Roles = "randomName")]" do mean randomName will change on the controller or just the value being passed in?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius where in the code the role would need to be added?

Comment: Parse the payload for the appropriate role and then something like `myPrincipal.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName))`

Comment: @Darkonekt I had the _principal.IsInRole(role) in my SetPrincipalAsync method, but it was failing. I thought something else needed to be done before that (adding the role, maybe), but I don't know where/how. Regarding the role, that role is being passed in and it would match to one of properties in JWT payload.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius The myPrincipal.Identity is type System.Security.Principal.IIdentity which does not have a AddClaim method!

Comment: You should be able to cast then maybe... `((ClaimsIdentity)myPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(...)`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I added the piece of code where I add the Claim(you can see it in the last method added), still no luck!